# multiple apache sites with dyndns

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, dyndns

Hi all i want to ask how is it possible to serve multiple sites hosted in my computer with apache through dyndns.I am using ubuntu 10.04 and i had setup a dyndns domain as of mydomain.homelinux.org/ .Also i had setup a virtual host with the below configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName  www.drupal-site.com
ServerAlias drupal-site.com

DocumentRoot /home/pavlos/Temp/websites/drupal-site/htdocs
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
</Directory>
<Directory /home/pavlos/Temp/websites/drupal-site/htdocs/>
Options FollowSymLinks 
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/pavlos/Temp/websites/drupal-site/cgi-bin/
<Location /cgi-bin>
            Options +ExecCGI
    </Location>


    # Logfiles
    ErrorLog  /home/pavlos/Temp/websites/drupal-site/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /home/pavlos/Temp/websites/drupal-site/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

My /etc/hosts file is:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost joomla-site.com drupal-site.com
127.0.1.1 medic
```

Now when i go to mydomain.homelinux.org outside of my lani see the default site of apache.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to have domains like:

www.joomla-site.com and joomla-site.com set up with a CNAME to mydomain.homelinux.org
and the same with www.drupal-site.com and drupal-site.com.

That way, when the person requests www.joomla-site.com, the Host header passed to apache is correct, rather than you seeing mydomain.homelinux.org.

You can do the same with an A record, but, a CNAME would not require you to configure the domains with an IP address, and when your dynamic DNS address is updated, your other two domains wouldn't need any DNS changes.